# RSocket- Expose service methods on request-response semantics

Tags: rsocket, rsocket-java

I am trying to expose all my backend service calls(all returns response to the calling client) via requestResponse paradigm in RSocket Implementation. To do that, either I have to use RPC or reflections. I do not want to go in the route of rsocket-RPC. Reflections drastically reduced the throughput. Please let me know if you have any solution or recommendation towards this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot with RSocket https://spring.io/blog/2020/03/02/getting-started-with-rsocket-spring-boot-server

It may use reflection for configuration, but should presumably have a fairly efficient method dispatch once the app is loaded.

Comment: Thank You, I reviewed it. I am trying to have more flexibility to start and manage multiple server. So trying to solve this one last hurdle in my implementation.